# Flutter Dynamic Links not opening on link TYPO

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, mobile, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm dealing with an error that when I create a shortLink example.com/xcdc and I modify it to i.e. example.com/xd, then the App is Opened, but i can't handle that case scenario. The log that i have in the console is only:

> 10.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800014] Cannot get flag for unregistered flag. SDK name, flag name: app_measurement, session_stitching_token_feature_enabled

> [] nw_path_necp_check_for_updates Failed to copy updated result (22)

I tried using the OnLink.Listen function, but it just won't work and it does not go into that function.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error.
In my case the link was

```
link: Uri.parse(
        'https://example.page.link/?mode=verifyEmail&lang=$lang&continueUrl=https://example.link/confirm_email?email=$email'),
```

that I change by

```
link: Uri.parse(
        'https://example.firebaseapp.com/?mode=verifyEmail&lang=$lang&continueUrl=https://example.link/confirm_email?email=$email'),
```

Here the full code

```
 Future<Uri> createDynamicLink(
    {required String email, required String lang}) async {
  final DynamicLinkParameters dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
    uriPrefix: 'https://example.page.link',
    link: Uri.parse(
        'https://example.firebaseapp.com/?mode=verifyEmail&lang=$lang&continueUrl=https://example.link/confirm_email?email=$email'),
    androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
      packageName: 'com.example.test',
      minimumVersion: 16,
    ),
    iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
      bundleId: 'com.example.test',
    ),
  );

  return FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(dynamicLinkParams);
}
```